# Goodness of fit for complex valued curves (i.e. frequency responses in frequency domain)

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, filter-design, estimation, frequency-response

My apologies for perhaps the stupidity of this question.

Presume that one has the 'frequency response' **$Y_{data}(k)$** of a system and also has an estimated model **$Y_{syn}(k)$** that fits the data.

How can I quantify the 'goodness of fit' of **$Y_{syn}(k)$** to **$Y_{data}(k)$** ? Notice that both curves are **complex-valued** at every instant ***k*** (i.e. frequency domain).

For example, assume that I have two estimated models: **$Y_{syn}^a(k)$** and **$Y_{syn}^b(k)$**. My goal (besides visualizing the residual) is to evaluate in a objective way the fit of both models to **$Y_{data}(k)$** (the original data set). Is there a single metric to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [$p$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) of the complex error $E(k)=Y_{data}(k)-Y_{syn}(k)$:

$$\epsilon_p=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{k=1}^K|E(k)|^p}\tag{1}$$

The most common values for $p$ are $p=2$ (Euclidean norm, $l_2$-norm) and $p=\infty$ (maximum norm or Chebyshev norm):

$$\epsilon_2=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^K|E(k)|^2}\tag{2}$$
$$\epsilon_{\infty}=\max_{1\le k\le K}\{|E(k)|\}\tag{3}$$

It eventually depends on your application which error measure best reflects the quality of the approximation. Note that for the maximum norm $(3)$, a single index $k$ determines the value of the error measure $\epsilon_{\infty}$, whereas the error measure $\epsilon_2$ in $(2)$ depends on all values of the complex error $E(k)$, and it is proportional to the square root of the mean squared error.

Comment: And if you have some other knowledge about why you want to weight the error for different $k$, you can include a weighting: $$\epsilon^2_p=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{k=1}^K|w(k)E(k)|^p}$$  This might be useful if you have known values of $k$ for which you need close agreement (little error), so you choose $w$ for those $k$ values to be larger.

Comment: @PeterK. Would you consider $1/k$ a possible weighting function, since usually you plot the frequency on a log scale, but the steps in frequency are constant, such that you have a lot more points at high frequencies. And what about normalizing the error ($\left|\frac{E(k)}{Y(k)}\right|^p$), to avoid big impacts of small relative errors at high magnitude values of $Y(k)$ (which is also why you normally plot magnitude in decibel/logarithmic)?

Comment: @fibonatic : yes, that makes sense. Sometimes a relative error is what you need. Not sure I'm convinced by $1/k$, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use common parameters, such as

- sum-of-squared-residuals $\chi^2$ or the reduced version $\chi^2/N$ ($N$ is the degrees of freedom)
- coefficient-of-determination $R^2$

Of course, you have to replace every square function by the square of the absolute value, i.e. $(x_i - \mu)^2 = (x_i - \mu)(x_i - \mu)^*$.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I upvoted your answer as well, but I'm not allowed due to my low rep.